# adb causing AdbCommandRejectedException device offline

Tags: adb

Adb is showing this exception in Android studio

PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device ZX1B32QXZV: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.

I have confirmed the dialog and even formatted my OS

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio go to the launch configuration ("Edit Configurations:...").
Then under Target Device: choose the following value

- Show chooser dialog

I had the same problem and had it set to "USB Device". This caused the connection to fail when trying to deploy to the emulator.