# "AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties... device unauthorized" PropertyFetcher issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having trouble running my application on a particular phone. It runs correctly on a different phone and on an emulator. I have the standard unauthorized issue coming up in my ADB logs:

> PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device [My Device's ID]: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.

When I try to run the application anyway on the phone in question, it is able to target the phone and runs the app, but immediately hits a null pointer (that isn't present when running on the other phone or the emulator).

Before you insta-lock this question, I've tried everything in all of the duplicate questions. Specifically

- [I have set the target to show chooser dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260869/adb-causing-adbcommandrejectedexception-device-offline)
- [I have reset the ADB server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079838/android-studio-adb-error-device-unauthorized-please-check-the-confirmat)
- [I have revoked and re-accepted permissions, and tried changing the USB type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079838/android-studio-adb-error-device-unauthorized-please-check-the-confirmat)
- [I have confirmed that Enable ADB Integration is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079838/android-studio-adb-error-device-unauthorized-please-check-the-confirmat)

None of which worked.

Furthermore, the same phone was working earlier (not sure what changed), so it's not a bad USB cord.

The phone is a new Nexus 6, and the old phone that works correctly is a Samsung Galaxy S4.

Running `adb devices` in the android studio terminal shows:

> List of devices attached
>
> [My Device's ID]      device

Which implies (?) that it is in fact authorized.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the Fingerprint Certificate Authorization popup in your phone when you connected it. To solve disconnect and plug-in again.Wait for some seconds and a confirmation popup will appear. Click OK.